# Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder doesn't serialize object

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, jsonserializer

I am using Spring Boot and it has it's own Jackson's default serialization.
It works not correctly in scope of my task.
So I want override Jackson's default serialization with my own custom serializator.
Here is my code:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            super.configure(objectMapper);
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
            simpleModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeCustomSerializer());
            objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        }
    }.serializerByType(ZonedDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(ZonedDateTime value,
                              JsonGenerator gen,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            gen.writeString(value.getNano() + "");
        }
    });
}


private class ZonedDateTimeCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ZonedDateTime> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(ZonedDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.getNano() + "");
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried some cases such as

- registering custom serializator through SimpleModule
- overriding `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder#serialize`

Please tip me how to override default Jackson serializator

Comment: What is your desired serialization and what you get? share all stuff that you tried.

Comment: you don't need it. it doesn't matter.
If I return time in milliseconds - it returns it in format xxxxx.00000000
I want to cut zeros after point.

Comment: why do you not use @JsonFormat in your Object?

Comment: because if I use annotation in my object - I need to annotate every object that has this property. But if configure serializator - other team members can even don't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[#Slowpokebreakingnews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxy6o.jpg)

If point is to add custom serializers - how about to [customize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilde by Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer()
{
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer()
    {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.serializerByType(CustomPojo.class, 
                                     new CustomSerializator<CustomPojo>());
            //affects to all dates in all pojos (I hope :) )
            builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat
                                                  ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));

        }
    };
}
```

For without-Spring-boot-configuration I override *configureMessageConverters()* :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
...
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) 
    {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new CustomObjectMapperBuilder();
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
    }

}
```

and define my *CustomJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder*:

```
public class CustomObjectMapperBuilder extends Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper)
    {
        super.configure(objectMapper);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Selective.class, new SelectiveSerializer());

        objectMapper.registerModule(module)
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true)
            .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For serializing date format you can do something like this

```
@Component
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{
private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");//yuor desired format goes here
@Override
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
gen.writeString(formattedDate);
}
}
```

You can do like your bean too.

And you have another option doing in your POJO like this

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")
private Date date;
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not best solution. I don't want annotate each Date, but to give this responsibility to serializer which will intercept each Date and serialize it.

Comment: if you use first part the second is not required

Comment: the annotation is another option